# Maven WAR Build for Tomcat: "Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]"

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, docker

There already some questions out there about this topic, but my Tomcat is still not running smoothly. 
My workspace is including jsf and spring. As long as Im building and running the project localy in eclipse and deploy it to my Tomcat in Eclipse, everything is working perfectly. But now I want to deploy the war file into an external Tomcat, in my case a Tomcat in a Docker-Container.  
 
So what I do is to: 
* build the WAR file with the following Maven-pom (extract). 
* And copying the war file to my running container like this:

> docker cp projectName.war containerID:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

During the Tomcat startup I always getting the following error.

In the beginning i had the applicationContext.xml-File directly in the WEB-INF Folder. But I read that it would be better to have it in "\WEB-INF\classes", so i moved it there, and did the following context-Location-parameter in the web.xml.

So the workspace-Hierarchy looks like in the following picture
projectName 
| -- WebContent 
    | -- WEB-INF 
| -- pom.xml

Another thing is that, when I extract the war file after the build to have a look where the applicationContext.xml-File actually is, I found it in "\WEB-INF\classes" but the context-Location-parameter in the web.xml is missing to locate to it. I also tryied to just put a copy of the applicationContext.xml-File it into *src/main/resources*, this led to, that the file at the right spot in the WAR file, but the web.xml changed.

Does someone has an advice where to put the applicationContext.xml-File and how to include and to point to it the right way in the build process. Also why is the web.xml changing during the build proces. Or is there a total different problem?

Thanks for help.

**pom.xml**

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <jsf.version>2.2.14</jsf.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSF Ende -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Ende -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>projectName</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>-->
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Startup Error**

```
2017-02-24 03:15:44 ERROR ContextLoader:351 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
... 25 more
24-Feb-2017 03:15:44.613 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-Feb-2017 03:15:44.614 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/projectName] startup failed due to previous errors
2017-02-24 03:15:44 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:987 - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Feb 24 03:15:44 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-24 03:15:44 WARN  XmlWebApplicationContext:1005 - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Feb 24 03:15:44 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:581)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4900)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5537)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
24-Feb-2017 03:15:44.622 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive
```

**web.xml**

```
  <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

[Workspace-Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTkR6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now after a while I made It.

1. "maven clean" because some dependencies got old and invalid. Thats why the web.xml was no more changing during a build
2. JSF dependencies were needed, so no more " provided "
3. The Docker Container had an JDK 7, but my app is build with JDK 8, so I changed the container to a Tomcat 8 with a JDK 8
4. Its was needed to tell the Maven-Build where the web.xml file is and which files should be included in the WAR-Build. I did this with the following Maven-Plugin: (also dont forget to add the Maven Dependencies to the "Deployment Assembly in Eclipse)

**maven-war-plugin**

```
<plugin>            
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<configuration>
   <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
   <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Have fun